# Qgis Python Multiprocessing, process do not update global variable and X11 connection broke after execution

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, qgis, hpc, x11-forwarding

I'm running QGIS3 on HPC(High-performance computing) using X11 forwarding through an SSH session.

I actually have to run a python code in Qgis3.
Instead of sequential computing, I'm trying to apply Parallelism to faster the process as HPC contains 24 cores.

There are 2 problems in code:

- Global Variable Updation
- X11 connection broke after the code execution in Qgis Python console.

Code:

```
from timeit import default_timer as dt
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Thread


st = dt()
count = 0

def counter(feats,vectors):
    cnt = 0
    for feature in feats:
        cands = vectors.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(feature.geometry().boundingBox()))
        for area_feature in cands:
            if feature.geometry().intersects(area_feature.geometry()):
                cnt+=1
    print(cnt)
    count+=cnt

veckey = list(QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().keys())[2]
vectorlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()[veckey]
key = list(QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().keys())[0]
grid = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()[key]

#splitting whole list into 4 parts for each process(core)
gfeats = np.array(list(grid.getFeatures()))
subs = np.array_split(gfeats,4)

threads = []

for sub in subs:
    proc = Process(target=counter,args=(sub,vectorlayer.clone())) #Creating process
    threads.append(proc)
    proc.start()

for proc in threads:
    proc.join()

print(count)
print(dt()-st)
```

Output:

```
0
27.3435636
```

But before I get this above input, each process is printing its individual count, when I summed them up the answer is correct but the processes are not updating the global variable **count**.

Please help me out in correcting this code and also please tell me why the HPC connection is getting broke.